# Laptop stuck at bios loading screen

Tags: hp-laptop

After installing an update I restarted my hp laptop. But now my laptop is stuck at the loading screen showing hp logo and a beep at about 10sec interval.

Comment: What update? info needed

Comment: @DrMoishePippik a synaptics smb touchpad update